# Help center page on what questions are on-topic here still says to ask Teams questions on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, help-center, stack-overflow-for-teams

In response to the 2022 dissociation of Teams from the main Stack Overflow site, in February 2023, the community there moved to change the scope of their meta to [no longer allow Teams questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423394/are-questions-about-stack-overflow-for-teams-on-topic-for-meta-stack-overflow-w). All prior Teams questions asked there have now been closed with a brand new off-topic sub-reason that directs users to open a ticket on the Teams support portal.

However, the [help center page on what topics are allowed here on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) still directs users to ask Teams questions on MSO.

As it's not good form for an official documentation page to direct someone to ask where the question would be closed anyway as off-topic, can the page be updated to direct Teams questions to the support portal instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've gone ahead and changed it - the bullet 'Questions about our Stack Overflow-centric products - these generally belong on Meta Stack Overflow.' was slightly misleading as well, so that section now reads:

> - Questions about our Stack Overflow-centric products
>
>   - For questions about [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/), please open a ticket in the [dedicated support portal](https://s.tk/support).
>   - Questions about [Collectives on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives) should be asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com).
>   - Questions about [Stack Overflow Talent](https://stackoverflow.co/talent/) should be asked directly to your account manager. If you don't know this contact person, please [call our Talent sales team](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact).

Improvements are welcome.